# CSRF - защита от подобных атак

Tags: php, безопасность, token, csrf

читаю про CSFR, не совсем понятно, почему не работает этот код:

```php
<? 
   session_start(); 
   $_SESSION["sid"] = md5(time() . rand(0, 10000)); 
 ?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>FORM</title>
</head>



<body>
  <div id="wrap">
    <form action="" method="POST">
      <input type="hidden" id="sid" name="sid" value="<?= $_SESSION["sid"]; ?>">
      <textarea cols="50" name="msg" rows="10"></textarea>
      <br>
      <input type="submit" name="sub" value="Send">
    </form>

  </div>
</body>
<script type="text/javascript">
</script>


<? 
   if(isset($_POST["sub"])) { 
         if(isset($_POST["sid"]) && $_POST["sid"]==$_SESSION["sid"]{ 
               $_SESSION["sid"]="" ; 
               echo "SUCCESS!"; 
         } else { 
               echo "ERROR!"; 
         } 
    } 
 ?>

</html>
```

выдает ERROR, понятно, что страница перезагружается.. но как тогда правильно сделать? название `"sid" = "token"`. Не обращайте внимания

Answer (score 1):

Вы генерируете CSRF-токен (который ещё зачем-то `sid`ом назвали) каждый раз заново. Разумеется, они никогда не будут равны.

Есть 2 пути решения проблемы:

1. Устанавливать CSRF-токен после того, как весь контент сгенерирован, но перед отправкой. Не подход в Вашем случае, поскольку у Вас HTML код перемежается с php-вставками. Если бы Вы использовали, скажем, шаблонизатор, этот подход мог бы выглядеть так:

   ```
   session_start(); 
   $response = generate_body(); // тут происходит вся обработка

   // тут можно выставить какие-нибудь заголовки
   $_SESSION["sid"] = md5(time() . rand(0, 10000));
   echo $response
   ```
2. Запоминать предыдущее значение токена и сравнивать с ним.

   ```
   $previous_token = $_SESSION["sid"]
   ```

Answer (score 0):

$_SESSION[ "sid"] не тоже самое что $_SESSION[" sid "]

Вверху

```
<?
session_start();  
if (!isset($_POST["sub"]))  
    $_SESSION["sid"] = md5(time() . rand(0, 10000));  
?>
```

Comment: исправил. но не в этом проблема

Comment: Дополнил ответ. У вас же переменная в сессии каждый раз перезаписывается, и вы сравниваете уже новое значение со старым. Проверил у себя, работает. Так же стоит проверить в нижних проверках наличие всех скобок ...

Answer (score 0):

У тебя генерации SID сделана зачем ? просто у сессии всегда есть SID , нативная функция его получения [session_id](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.session-id.php)

не нужно ничего запоминать просто в html в нужном месте вставляй session_id и сравнивай с ним же .